# The distribution of a random variable related to a sequence

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $A_i$, $i=1,2,3,..,k$ be $k$ integers uniformly and randomly chosen from $[-n,n]$ i.e the  set of integers between $-n$ and $n$ for some given $n$ and $A_{k+1}=1$. Now consider the sequence $(A_1,A_2,\dots,A_k,A_{k+1})$ and define two random variables $X$ and $Y$ as:

$$X=\text{Number of negative or zero terms before  the first positive term} $$ and $$Y=\max\{|A_i|:A_i<0\}$$.Here are my thoughts :
$$P(A_i\leq 0)=\frac{n+1}{2n+1},i=1,2,..,k$$.If we think of $X$ as the number of failures preceding the first success in a certain number of binomial trials, I wonder whether one can find out the distribution of $X$ using negative binomial distribution? As for $Y$
$$P(A_i<0)=\frac{n}{2n+1}$$  and the possible values absolute values are $1,2,,...n$ each having the same probability.Can we find the pdf of $Y$ using the concept of order statistics?How can we find the distribution of $X$ and $Y$ exactly?Lots of thanks for any clarifications\hints\ressponces.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: You may want to write $A_i$ in capital letters, and you may want to define $Y$ in the case when none of the $A_i$ are negative.

Comment: @Jose Avilez ,i edited the question